# PDO connection not working for un unknown reason with Wamp

Tags: php, pdo, wamp

I've created a database named "code_postaux" with Wamp and I'd like to access it (in local  first)  using the PHP language. When I try to connect the database I get the message "getMessage()); } ?>".

my php file :

```
<?php
try
{
   $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=code_postaux', 'root', '', $pdo_options);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

EDIT (what I see in the browser source code) :

```
<?php
try
{
   $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=code_postaux', 'root', '', $pdo_options);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

the font color is pink from the beginning of the text to $e->

Comment: Is this your entire code? What you describe suggests you have a `?>` somewhere before `getMessage` call.

Comment: @Mchl This is my entire PHP code.

Comment: If you're running this in browser, could you use 'View source' option and tell us what you see there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your server is not configured to parse PHP files. Your file has been sent to browser without interpreting it first. Make sure your extension is .php. If it is, you need to provide us with details of your server config. Did you open this page using http://localhost address? Or did you just double click the PHP file?

You might also want to take this to https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks I'll check this. Actually I'm using a local webpage with a form and a submit button to access (trying :-)) the database.

Comment: If you're using Wampserver, all your pages need to be under (by default) `c:\wamp\www` folder, and you need to access them via http://localhost address in your browser. Otherwise they will not be processed by PHP

Answer (score 1):

Have you check if the extension is initialized ?

If you're not sure check the php.ini file and a line with :

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

Comment: And in you php_info what did you find in extension enable ?

Comment: I know of php.ini but I've never heard of php_info

Comment: I've put it just after <?php but I get nothing.

Comment: @luckytaxi I get a blank screen

Comment: I'm venturing a guess that PHP is not working on your server. Both your question, and the trouble with phpinfo() suggest that you code is just being parsed by the browser.